# Pattern matching natural powers as products

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, rule

I thought that Mathematica would be smart enough to know that `f[t]^2` should match `a_ * b_` with `a` and `b` both taking the value `f[t]`, but it doesn't.

I'm writing some rules for identities involving products. It's mainly finding different ways of doing integration by parts. Am I forced to write separate rules for handling powers, or can Mathematica be persuaded to match`f[t]^2` as `a_ * b_`?

I would like to handle arbitrarily large natural powers, so `f[t]^3` should match `a_ * b_` with `a` as `f[t]` and `b` as `f[t]^2`, or vice versa. `f[t]^4` should match as both `f[t] * f[t]^3` and `f[t]^2 * f[t]^2`. I'm using `ReplaceList`, so the order is unimportant. I want the behaviour to be identical to if the powers were represented as `f[t] * f[t] * f[t] ...`.

If not, is there a nice single pattern I can use to match all cases? I've been looking at `Alternatives`, but I don't know how to capture the `a` and `b` values properly when dealing with the powers forms.

Comment: The former has a head `Power` while the latter `Times`. Seen from this single fact, they two do not match of course. It is not a matter of being smart or not. Pattern matching is performed based on the form of an expression, not its (mathematical) meaning. Using jargon, pattern matching is performed syntactically, not semantically.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I understand that. There are attributes like `Flat` that allow semantic matching that deviates from those strict rules and I assumed that there would be similar special handling for `Power`, although I realise now that there isn't. That's quite inconvenient, because when I have an expression featuring `a * b`, and `a` happens to equal `b` at some point, MMA automatically transforms it into a power, then all of my rules stop working. Do you know of any concise pattern that is able to match either form interchangably while giving the `a` and `b` values?

Comment: Two suggestions. You can try to use functions like `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, etc. to stop MMA from evaluations before matchings; because MMA "thinks" `Power` is simpler than `Times` when multiplying factors are the same. Or why do you not just using `Power` to construct the matching rules?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I can write matching rules directly using `Power`, but they would be duplicates of ones I've already written that use `Times`. Although I'm not sure how to get the exact functionality I need. I'm using `ReplaceList` to get every possible match with `a_ * b_`, but I don't know how to write a rule for `Power` that gives all of the different forms of `f[t]^4` like `f[t] * f[t]^3` and `f[t]^2 * f[t]^2`. The best idea I have is to do this in two stages, first transforming all `Times` and `Power` into a new head `myTimes` then doing my matching against that. That feels like a hack.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I don't think I can easily use `Hold` etc, because I'm passing these expressions through other functions that transform them too. I'll have another read of the docs in case I'm missing something that I could do there.

Comment: Maybe a [Default Pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) could help. Default patterns like `a_^b_.` would automatically give you the exponent of each factor (even if the exponent is `b==1`) and you can write one set of rules for all cases.

Comment: Could you please expand on that @Roman? I have an inkling of how that could be useful, but I'm not seeing how to make that do the thing of matching `f[t]^4` as both `f[t] * f[t]^3` and `f[t]^2 * f[t]^2` in `ReplaceList`. If you could give that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By replacing multiplication with [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html), which is an associative but noncommutative symbol with no built-in meaning, you can preprocess your expressions in the desired explicit form:

```
expr = a^3 + b c (1 + c + c^2);

A = Expand[expr] /. {Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply,
                     x_^n_Integer :> NonCommutativeMultiply @@ ConstantArray[x, n]}

(*    b ** c + a ** a ** a + b ** c ** c + b ** c ** c ** c    *)
```

From here you can continue applying your rules by pattern-matching, for example

```
A /. {x_ ** y_ ** z_ ** w_ :> func4[x, y, z, w],
      x_ ** y_ ** z_ :> func3[x, y, z],
      x_ ** y_ :> func2[x, y]}

(*    func2[b, c] + func3[a, a, a] + func3[b, c, c] + func4[b, c, c, c]    *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've marked this as the answer because it does get me what I need. It's similar to the method I already mentioned in the comments, and I had hoped for something more concise that didn't involve multiple steps and transforming the expression before matching against it. If somebody is able to provide a better answer I'll probably switch to accepting that, but I think this is probably about as good as it gets.

It feels like an oversight that MMA doesn't have an attribute similar to `Flat` and `Orderless` to support this automatically out of the box.